# Chrome plugin edits the page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, plugins

I have a problem, I want to write a plugin that will edit the page and I can write a plugin, but I don't know how to make a plugin that will edit the page (javascript)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel, just use an extension that injects code.

For example: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-manipulator/mdhellggnoabbnnchkeniomkpghbekko?hl=en

Comment: if I wanted to inject the code, I would use the "Inspect" function in the browser and I want to write my own extension that will somehow change the page